# The page isn’t redirecting properly was given when redirecting

Tags: javascript, wp-redirect

This question has been asked by many people. In my Wordpress site I need to redirect to to xyz page after submitting the form. I have tried following solutions so far and non of them are working for me. Can anyone help me with this. Thank you in advance.
method 1

```
header("Location: http://www.local.abc.com/xyz");exit;
```

method 2

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='http://www.local.abc.com/xyz';</script>";
```

method 3

```
wp_redirect('http://www.local.abc.com/xyz', 301 );
exit;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Where you place method 3 for example? Please provide more information.

Comment: In my Wordpress site I need to redirect to to xyz page after submitting the form

Comment: So you are submitting a form? Please provide your code. How you submit, how you process the form, when or where you redirect etc

Comment: When I redirect to a url like www.google.com, it works fine. This happens only when I redirect to same domain url address

Comment: That's an info you should add in your question. It took me 3 comments to get that. Please read [How to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am just trying to redirect. When I am submitting the form I am sending as mail as well. It is working fine

Comment: Really sorry about it